# Symfony 2.0.9 Error on updating

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, bundle

when running `php bin/vendors install` i get the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\DoctrineCommand' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\myproject\vendor\bundles\Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineCommand.php on line 18

And here is my deps file:
http://pastebin.com/FZYRzaFb
Is there a way i can fix this, maybe by setting different versions of bundles in deps files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly, you must use `version=origin/2.0` for the SensioGeneratorBundle
See [this thread](https://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle/commit/0d58617cbde570803c2f00dc03f3acffce0cf28f#commitcomment-839648)

Comment: it is alreadyy like that if you look at the deps file...someone told me on IRC that it could be something with deps.lock, but i have no idea what exactly needs to be done.

Comment: @Confidence: you need to run `php bin/vendors update` , if you `php bin/vendors install` you will stay locked.

Comment: ok, i managed to fix it by completely overwriting my deps with original from 2.0.9 release, then running

php bin/vendors update

Comment: This does what I said I think

Comment: You can click on the tick left to it, and upvote it with the arrow above the "0"